# Querying Active directory

Tags: java, active-directory

I want to query user credentials against an Active Directory without the user entering his credentials. i.e The user logs into his corporate system(Intranetwork) i need to use these credentials to verify against an AD and retrieve his email address if the user exists.(NO single sign on required)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, It is too late to answer, but ... someone like me can search same answer...

I'm just not sure why do you need to verify user credentials? 
If user already logged-in then ... credentials are verified.

Getting his email (and other info from AD) is possible by using Windows powershell.

```
public class TestWindowsAD {

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Current user e-mail: " + getCurrentUserEmail());

}

private static String getCurrentUserEmail() {

    String cmd = "powershell \"Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::Current.EmailAddress;\"";
    String userEmail = "";
    if (!System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().startsWith("win")) { throw new RuntimeException(
            "We are not in Windows! OS is " + System.getProperty("os.name")); }
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr;
    try {
        pr = rt.exec(cmd);
        pr.waitFor();
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        String nextLine = null;

        while (true) {
            nextLine = bf.readLine();
            if (nextLine == null) break;
            userEmail = nextLine;
        }
        bf.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to get user email: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return userEmail;
}
```

P.S. if you need more info just run in command prompt:

```
powershell "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::Current"
```

and pick what you need.